# XSLT - Add new attribute to existing node by checking existing attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Hi I have following xml,

```
<doc>
 <footnote>
   <p type="Footnote Text">
       <link ref="http://www.facebook.org"/>
   </p>
 </footnote>
<footnote>
   <p type="Footnote Text">
       <link ref="http://www.wiki.org"/>
   </p>
 </footnote>
<footnote>
   <p type="Footnote Paragraph">
       <link ref="http://www.wiki.org"/>
   </p>
 </footnote>
</doc>
```

what I need to do is add new attribute (id='number-1') to `<p>` nodes where its attribute `type` is eqal to `Footnote Text`. in this case only first two `<p>` nodes should apply the new `<id>` attribute.

so I wrote following code,

```
<xsl:template match="p/@type[.='Footnote Text']">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="id">
         <xsl:value-of select="'number-'"/><xsl:number level="any"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

but it does not add the new attribute to `<p>` node. however when I remove the `@type[.='Footnote Text']` it adds the new node to all `<p>` nodes as expected.

my intended output is follows

```
<doc>
   <footnote>
      <p type="Footnote Text" id="number-1">
          <link ref="http://www.facebook.org"/>
      </p>
   </footnote>
   <footnote>
     <p type="Footnote Text" id="number-2>
        <link ref="http://www.wiki.org"/>
     </p>
   </footnote>
   <footnote>
     <p type="Footnote Paragraph">
       <link ref="http://www.wiki.org"/>
     </p>
   </footnote>
 </doc>
```

How can I filter the `<p>` nodes that have type="Footnote Text" attribute and add new attribute to those `<p>` nodes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the attribute to the element:

```
<xsl:template match="p[@type = 'Footnote Text']">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="id">
         <xsl:value-of select="'number-'"/><xsl:number count="p[@type = 'Footnote Text']" level="any"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```